# Eclipse CDT : automating Organize Includes

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

Is there an option to automate the `context menu/Source/Optimize includes` functionality? Perhaps on file save, or on exiting or starting the IDE ...

Failing that, is there a plug-in?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean Organize Includes.

I'm not aware of a built-in way to configure that to run after every file-save, nor of a plugin that would do it.

Consider [filing a bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=CDT) requesting that an option to run Organize Include be added to Preferences -> C/C++ -> Editor -> Save Actions.